# Specifying both -O2 and -O3 at same time

Tags: gcc, clang, compiler-optimization

Some programs already uses -O2 flag, if I use -O3 flag, the program compiles with both -O2 and -O3 as shown by the task manager or by `/proc/PID/cmdline`.

For example, I'm using a Linux kernel built with Clang and full LTO. Even though I have these lines in the dkms configuration:

```
# /etc/dkms/framework.conf
export LLVM=1
export CC=clang
export CFLAGS="-O3 -march=native"
```

Now DKMS modules compile with both `-O2` and `-O3` flags. In this case, which flag is actually used?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For gcc, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-11.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options

> If you use multiple `-O` options, with or without level numbers, the last such option is the one that is effective.

clang doesn't document its option syntax as extensively, but it generally tries to be compatible with gcc, so it should be the same in this regard.